# Does this git command revert a github repository back to a point in the past?

Tags: git, github

Person A pushed his files to a github repository, and then person B pushed his file to the same github repository.

A didn' like B's commit, and recovered the github repository back to where it was before B's push. A claimed to use the following command to accomplish that

```
git push origin master -f
```

and I might misunderstand some part of command, because I am not familiar with the stuff.

A hasn't changed anything in his local repository since his push.

My questions are

- why can't I find B's commit in the history of the github repository?
- why is there only one commit by A, just like what it was before B's push?
- What does the command that A used do?  Revert everything back to the point before B's push?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably what happened:

- initially, in the github repository, the *master* branch points to commit 1.
- B pushes his changes. This consists of two things:

  - sending his commit (commit 2) to the remote repository
  - telling the remote server that the *master* branch now no longer points to commit 1, but to commit 2.
- A uses the `git push origin master -f`, telling the remote repository to move the *master* branch reference back to commit 1 again (or to whatever commit his current *master* branch points to).

Now, to answer your questions:

> why can't I find B's commit in the history of the github repository?
>   why is there only one commit by A, just like what it was before B's push?

B's commit is still there, but it's no longer being referenced by any branch. When you do `git log` being on *master*, you only see the commit that this branch points to and all its ancestors. Any other commits that are children of commit 1 or unrelated to commit 1 will not be shown.

The only way I found to list an orphan commit is to do `git reflog` on a machine that recently had that commit checked out.

> What does the command that A used do? Revert everything back to the point before B's push?

See the third bullet above.

Answer (score 2):

The `-f` flag stands for force. I can only guess, but what probably happened was that A didn't have B's change yet so in order to "revert" B's change, all A had to do was force-push.

- B's commit is not present in the log because A force-pushed a repository that did not have the change at all
- See previous
- Not exactly. By itself it doesn't revert things, but to erase history like A did you would need to use a force push eventually.